# How to manipulate the current time in Javascript (several times and add it into a table)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**What I want to do:**

I want to change the current time repeatedly and display them in different table rows in my HTML document.

**Example:**

I want to get the time that was 10, 20, 60 and 71 minutes ago from the current time. So if the current time on my computer is 23:00 (in Europe) now, it should give me 22:50, 22:40, 22:00 and 21:49.

**What I have done so far:**

I managed to change the time once but I am not sure how to change it a several times (maybe with a "for" or "while"-Loop?) and add them all to a table in my html document.

This is my .js:

```
window.setInterval("showpasttime()", 1000); 
function showpasttime()
  {
   d = new Date ();
   d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()-10);          //gives me current minutes MINUS 10 minutes
   month = d.getMonth () + 1;
   h = (d.getHours () < 10 ? '0' + d.getHours () : d.getHours ());
   m = (d.getMinutes () < 10 ? '0' + d.getMinutes () : d.getMinutes ());


   document.getElementById("row2").innerHTML = '10 minutes ago it was '
        + d.getDate () + '.'
        + month + '.'
        + d.getFullYear () +
        ' - '
        + h + ':' + m ;
  };
```

**Result so far:**

In my html document the "10 minutes ago it was 5.3.2014 - 22:50" goes into the tablerow with the id ="row2".

**Problem/Question:**

Now I want to do that repeatedly for other time spans (again for example 20, 60 and 71 minutes ago). Do I have to write this code again and again or is there a more elegant way to do this e.g. with a "for" or "while"-function? 
Thanks a lot (and I hope this question is not too stupid since I am absolutely new to html/css/javascript/jquery).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DEMO (/w jQuery)](http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/AUdLb/)

[DEMO (/wo jQuery)](http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/F97uk/)

Make it just a deterministic function. This way it will work for any number of minutes regardless. Your spec can easily change and the code is more re-usable. The name should probably change to something like `getMinutesAgo` from `showpasttime` just to make it more semantic with intent.

```
function getMinutesAgo(ago){
   d = new Date ();
   d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()-ago);
   month = d.getMonth () + 1;
   h = (d.getHours () < 10 ? '0' + d.getHours () : d.getHours ());
   m = (d.getMinutes () < 10 ? '0' + d.getMinutes () : d.getMinutes ());


   return ago + ' minutes ago it was '
        + d.getDate () + '.'
        + month + '.'
        + d.getFullYear () +
        ' - '
        + h + ':' + m ;
  };
```

Then consume as needed. Beyond that the demo is just my preferences.

Comment: Nice answer. In the demos where you compare value less than to determine if you should add a leading zero did you mean to have 10 rather than ago?

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. @ Jason Aller: I think you're right: If you change the "ago" in the "h" and "m" variable back to 10, the script works perfectly (since the logic here is: if the minutes/hours are smaller than 10, just add a 0 infront of it, so it looks superduper great like "09:01" for example :).

Comment: @ Fresheyeball: I've tried to use your code (with jQuery) as well since with your code I could use one "time ago-time point" more often. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I tried to call the function in the body of the html-document with: <script> getMinutesAgo(ago); </script> but unfortunately nothing happens. Could you give me a hint how to implement your code into the html-document or how to call the function/code (I guess that's completely a newbie question but with zsaat14 and net.uk.sweet's code, it worked by calling the function as mention above)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, thank you, now it works after I've tried your link [link](jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/AUdLb/5) (by putting part of the function into the head of the html document). Great!

Comment: @Fresheyeball One last question/problem: When I am using your code from [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/AUdLb/5) there is a short time lag before the "time points" load. That means: Everything else in my table has already been loaded when the "time points" appear (a bit later). Maybe it's because of jQuery? Could you please show me how to implement the "/wo jQuery"-Code into my HTML Document? Again: In jsFiddle it worked fine (like in your DEMO wo jQuery) but when I copy the exact code in a local .html (and/or in an external .js-file), your code won't work. Thanks again!

Comment: beautiful, your last suggestion works perfectly. Thank you! http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/AUdLb/7

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LxeQ8/10/).  The best way to do this is to put your time deductions in an array and iterate through it with a for loop.

**Final JS:**

```
var deductions = [10, 20, 60, 71]; //Set your deductions here
window.setInterval(showpasttime(), 1000);
function showpasttime(){
    for(i=0;i<deductions.length;i++){ //Iterate through the time deductions in the array
        d = new Date ();
        d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()-deductions[i]); //gives me current minutes MINUS specified number of minutes minutes
        month = d.getMonth () + 1;
        h = (d.getHours () < 10 ? '0' + d.getHours () : d.getHours ());
        m = (d.getMinutes () < 10 ? '0' + d.getMinutes () : d.getMinutes ());
        document.getElementById("row"+i).innerHTML = deductions[i]+' minutes ago it was '
            + d.getDate () + '.'
            + month + '.'
            + d.getFullYear () +
            ' - '
            + h + ':' + m ;
     }
};
```

**HTML:**

Since the JS is looking for `"row"+i`, you need this HTML:

```
<div id='row0'></div>
<div id='row1'></div>
<div id='row2'></div>
<div id='row3'></div>
```

`i` starts at 0 and will increment through 3 because you have 4 time deductions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly! I just changed the "deductions[i]" in the "h" and "m" variable back to 10 (because: If the minutes or hours are smaller than 10, just add a 0 infront of it, so the format looks like for example like this: 09:01).

Comment: @user3385759 Ah, yes.  I'll change my answer to reflect that.  I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @user3385759 If you found this answer or another answer helpful, you can accept the best answer: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

You could put the time offsets in an `array` and iterate over that in your `for` loop:

```
// Create an array with the offsets in it
var offsets = [10, 20, 60, 71];

window.setInterval("showpasttime()", 1000); 
function showpasttime() {
    // Iterate over the array of times
    for (var i = 0; i < offsets.length; i ++) {
       d = new Date ();
       d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()-offsets[i]);          //gives me current minutes MINUS 10 minutes
       month = d.getMonth () + 1;
       h = (d.getHours () < 10 ? '0' + d.getHours () : d.getHours ());
       m = (d.getMinutes () < 10 ? '0' + d.getMinutes () : d.getMinutes ());

       // Use the loop counter to target each row of your table
       document.getElementById("row" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = offsets[i] + 'minutes ago it was '
            + d.getDate () + '.'
            + month + '.'
            + d.getFullYear () +
            ' - '
            + h + ':' + m ;
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I think this is the most beautiful answer (for a Newbie like me).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:  this works well

http://jsfiddle.net/zjjbn/1/

```
var minutes=[10,20,60,71];
var newDate = [];

for(var i=0; i <minutes.length;i++){
   var now = new Date();   //your date
   newDate[i] = new Date(now.getTime() + minutes[i]*60*1000);
   alert(newDate[i]);
}  // now you have a new array  newDate[]  with your new dates
```

Comment: so you can put your minutes in an array and use a for loop to go trough them

Comment: You can just edit your answer rather than adding a comment to it.